# Jersey client with multi domain uri

Tags: jersey, rest-client

I am using Jersey Client API to talk to REST server.
Client is having problem in connecting to URL with multiple sub-domains.
EX : https://domain1.domain2.abc.com.
This throws 503 service unavailable.
i trusted all the certs and bypassed host name verification.
Even with HttpsUrlConnection API i get the same 503 error.

But when i hit the same URL with CURL that works fine.

I see the Client API works well with https://domain2.optum.com.

Is there any restriction for Jersey Client (HttpsUrlConnection)API with sub domain names in the URL?